# Why does my set-cookie erases after I do a subsequest request

Tags: angular, typescript, go, cors

The problem is that when I log in using a endpoint, it return in the response header a set-cookie which is a http only cookie, but when I do other requests for other endpoints, I don't see the set-cookie in the request headers, I have tried to fix this issue

below is the angular code inside a service.ts,

```
private apiUrl = environment.baseUrl +  '/api/v1/login';
private apiUrl2 = environment.baseUrl + '/api/v1/anotherRequest';
login(req: Login): Observable<string> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return this.httpClient.post<string>(this.apiUrl,JSON.stringify(req),{ headers })
  }
anotherRequestBeingMade(): Observable<any]> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
   
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.apiUrl2,{withCredentials:true})
  }
```

this is how I set up my http only cookie in fiber using golang

```
cookie := fiber.Cookie{
        Name:     "my_cookie",
        Value:    *thereisavaluehere,
        Expires:  time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24),
        HTTPOnly: true,
        Secure:   true,
        SameSite: "None",
        Path:     "/",
    }

    c.Cookie(&cookie)
```

I test it on Postman, and it sets the cookie on the login endpoint which has the response header `Set-Cookie`. When doing the subsequent request it shows on the request header `Cookie` but when I tested on the Angular client, `Set cookies` is still present when doing the login endpoint but the `Cookie` header is not available in subsequent request.

What I have tried:

- I have included the `{withCredentials:true}`  inside the get httpClient
- I have tried fixing the cors issue in my backend which is written in golang

```
  app.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
       AllowOrigins:     "http://localhost:4200",
       AllowHeaders:     "Origin, Content-Type, Accept",
       AllowMethods:     "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
       ExposeHeaders:    "Set-Cookie",
       AllowCredentials: true,
   }))
```

- Tried the bypass proxy by creating a proxy.conf.json in the same level as the package.json and configured the package.json script object, section start with

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

```
{
"/api/*": {
  "target": "http://localhost:8080",
  "secure": false,
  "logLevel": "debug"
}
}
```

Then I added a enviroment.ts file in the src folder of the angular app which has

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080' // Adjust this to match your backend server URL
  };
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried your browser's developer tools to see if the cookie is saved? The cookies show be in the Storage tab. That'll tell you if the problem is on the Go side, or the Javascript side.

Comment: I just checked and the Http cookie is not displaying in the dev tools, is it a backend end problem?

Comment: Also, it saves the cookie in postman but in the client side it doesn't save it

Comment: The cookie isn't saved by your browser because browsers silently reject attempts by insecure Web origins like `http://localhost:8080` (note the scheme: `http`, not `https`) to set a cookie marked `Secure`. Besides, because `Set-Cookie` is a so-called [forbidden reasponse-header name](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name), attempts to expose that header to the client won't work.

Comment: Setting secure to false, would lead to solving this issue? I have tried this, and it doesn't work

Comment: Typically REST calls use other authentication methods besides cookies, such as a Bearer token or [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JWt_(Java_web_toolkit)). The reason being that if you use an insecure browser that ignores CORS headers, any site's JavaScript code can make a call to the endpoint, and the user's browser will happily send along its cookie.

Comment: @JosieGPT No, it won't work either, because `SameSite=None` requires `Secure` in several modern browsers. Here's what you can do in your development environment: because the client (`http://localhost:4200`) and server (`http://localhost:8080`) are [same-site](https://site-and-origin.securitum.com/), you can set the cookie with simply `SameSite=Lax` and without a `Secure` attribute. That should work.

Comment: @amphetamachine You don't need an insecure browser and you don't need CORS for making a script send cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed the fact that I left out the `withcredentials:true` to the httpclient on my login api

```
login(req: Login): Observable<string> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return this.httpClient.post<string>(this.apiUrl,JSON.stringify(req),{headers,withCredentials:true})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I log in using a endpoint, it return in the response header a set-cookie which is a http only cookie, but when I do other requests for other endpoints, I don't see the set-cookie in the request headers"

That isn't an issue.  [The `Set-Cookie` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) only needs to be set on login.  It does not need to be specified in response to every request to "maintain" the cookie's presence.

The client analogue is [the `Cookie` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie).  Check your browser's developer tools to be sure subsequent requests include the `Cookie` header.

Comment: The http cookie is not displaying in the dev tools

Comment: Verify you're looking in the right place for this stuff by playing with https://httpbin.org/#/Cookies/get_cookies_set and https://httpbin.org/#/Cookies/get_cookies and viewing the headers of the different commands in the network request inspector.  Note that `cookie` and `set-cookie` are not available in javascript's list of headers, so you can't output them that way in the JS console.